# Remove harddisk from "Dell Latitude D530"

Tags: hard-drive, dell-latitude

I am trying to fix a laptop that will not start. The error is that it cannot read a value from the registry.

As a first step I am trying to take out the harddisk to make a copy.

Question is where is the harddisk on a "Dell Latitude D530"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hard drive is mounted in an easy-to-remove drive bay.  Two M3 screws fix the bay from the bottom, after removing them you can pull out the bay. You need a PH0 screwdriver, you do not need to remove any cables for removing the drive (the drive directly connects to a backplane inside the hard drive slot).

Have a look at the [Dell Latitude D530 service manual](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/latd530/en/sm/hdd.htm#wp1180206) for in-detail instructions with images included.